# Use constraint inside a validator

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm using symfony2 validator to validate a form and an API POST request.

I have made my validator like this :

```
public function validate($content, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (in_array($constraint->type, self::DNS_TYPE, true) === false) {
        $this->context->buildViolation('This DNS type is not valid.')
            ->atPath($constraint->type)
            ->addViolation();
    }

    switch ($constraint->type) {
        case 'A':
            $contentConstraint = new Assert\Ip(['version' => '4']);
            break;
        case 'AAAA':
            $contentConstraint = new Assert\Ip(['version' => '6']);
            break;
        case 'CNAME':
        case 'NS':
        case 'MX':
            $contentConstraint = new Assert\Regex(['pattern' => '/^[[:alnum:]-\._]+$/u']);
            break;
        default:
            $contentConstraint = false;
            break;
    }

    // This part don't work
    if ($this->validate('1.1.1.1', $contentConstraint)) {
        $this->context->buildViolation('his value is not correct.')
            ->atPath($content)
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

The first callback and the switch work with my form but when the second callback is used, symfony return an error

> The option "type" does not exist in constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Ip

I don't understand what is wrong with my constraint.
Why this error say that my ip constraint don't have the `type` option ?

How can I fix this ?
I can maybe not use `ip` constraint in a validator ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Ip.html not have the `type` property. 
If you need it, you should extend `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Ip`

Comment: I don't need this property, I don't even know where this property is coming from. When I'm using this in another class, this is working well. I don't understand why only in this class I have this error